# Convertendo HttpPostedFileBase para byte[] : Exception_WasThrown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Segue código:

**Controller (com ação post):**

```
var file = Request.Files[0];
var bytes = ConvertTo.Bytes(file);
```

**Classe ConvertTo :**

```
public static byte[] Bytes(HttpPostedFileBase result)
{
    var length = result.InputStream.Length; //Length: 103050706
    MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
    result.InputStream.CopyTo(target); // gera problema nessa linha aqui
    byte[] data = target.ToArray(); 
    return data;
}
```

O arquivo tem tamanho de: 98,2 MB (103.050.706 bytes), arquivo de tamanho 60 MB funciona perfeitamente.

Na linha: `result.InputStream.CopyTo(target);` recebo erro:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception_WasThrown'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo pequeno funciona bem, só arquivo grande faz esse problema.

Alguma solução para arquivo grande ?

**UPDATE:**

Segue código:

```
public static byte[] ConverToBytes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var length = file.InputStream.Length; //Length: 103050706
    byte[] fileData = null;
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
    {
        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
    }
    return fileData;
}
```

Código acima funciona usando `BinaryReader`. Porque `MemoryStream` não funciona ?

Comment: Matheus, quais são as versões do IIS, .NET runtime e do ambiente operacional que você está utilizando? 32 ou 64 bits?

Comment: @OnoSendai 10.0.16299.15 e Windows 10. É 64 bits, No projeto está como 32 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá, não sei como o MemoryStream funciona por dentro, mas fiz um profiler no seu método e no método que fiz que acho que ficaria mais 'leve'.

Pela exception o problema é falta de memória então pensei em um código que poderia resolver o problema contando com sua limitação de memória.

Tomei a liberdade de colocar o parâmetro como Stream e não HttpPostedFile para facilitar o teste.

Para o teste utilizei o instalador do RapidMiner que tem mais ou menos 171MB.

Abaixo está o resultado com seu código, não sei porque utilizou tanta memória:

```
public static byte[] Bytes2(Stream result)
        {
            var length = result.Length; //Length: 103050706
            MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
            result.CopyTo(target); // gera problema nessa linha aqui
            byte[] data = target.ToArray();
            return data;
        }
```

[image: Com MemoryStream]

Abaixo eu fiz utilizando um código sem realizar a instância de MemoryStream, veja a diferença:

```
    public static byte[] Bytes(Stream result)
    {
        long length = result.Length;
        byte[] data = new byte[length];
        result.Read(data, 0, (int)length); //até int.max está ok

        return data;
    }
```

[image: Sem MemoyStream]

Tente usar esse segundo código e me fale se o problema foi resolvido.

Comment: Seu código funcionou, sem problema. Você sabe me dizer porque com `BinaryReader` funciona ?

Comment: Não tenho certeza amigo, acredito que o MemoryStream faça um buffer e aloque mais dados que o necessário imaginando que você vai trabalhar mais nele depois, já o Read é mais claro o que faz, apenas copia para um vetor.

Comment: Entendo. Como você abriu essa janela onde mostra as informações dos bytes ?

Comment: É o Visual Studio Performance profiler, as versoes mais caras do Visual Studio tem, ai você pode acessar por aqui: https://imgur.com/a/65VwL    Ai, eu utilizo bastante para ver onde está lento alguma parte do sistema, tem outros dados legais como tempo de execução em cada função, etc... Depois pesquisa mais sobre ele, é interessante.

Answer (score 5):

O `MemoryStream` cria um buffer interno com um valor predefinido, que só cresce de acordo com a demanda dos dados passados.

Caso os dados que você passe ultrapassem o tamanho que foi pre-alocado, é **criado um** **novo** buffer com o **dobro do tamanho**, que recebe todo o conteúdo do buffer antigo.

Por exemplo: Se for alocado 128mb de memória e seu arquivo consumir mais que isso, o `MemoryStream` tentará alocar 256mb, e assim pro diante, dobrando o tamanho, tornando o recurso extremamente custoso.

Esse erro pode ter a ver com as configurações do processo da aplicação também, caso esteja em 32bits. Tente dar um build na sua aplicação com a configuração de `x64`.

Usei como referência essa resposta do [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static byte[] Bytes(HttpPostedFileBase result)
{
    byte[] data;
    using (Stream inputStream = result.InputStream)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            inputStream.CopyTo(ms);
            data = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Você instanciou o `MemoryStream` duas vezes em `MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;` e `inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);`. Foram linhas que não faziam sentido no código.

Acima, um `MemoryStream` é criado em uma nova instância. Os bytes de `inputStream` são copiados para `ms`, e assim, retornado.

Answer (score -3):

Uma boa saída é redimensionar essa imagem.

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail(string filename)
{
var img = new WebImage(filename).Resize(291, 285, false, true);
return new ImageResult(new MemoryStream(img.GetBytes()), "binary/octet-stream");
}
```

[Documentação da classe WebImage, no MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx)